# random number C

Tags: c, random

Have to write a function return a square of number from 50 to 100, without using a seed and take no parameters.

I know how to generate a random number in a fixed range (for example 0 to 99):

```
   int n;
   n=rand(100);  /* n is random number in range of 0 - 99 */
```

**EDIT:**
By the way, I used `rand()` and every time I run it give me same result. I know it because of my compiler, is there anyways to change it (remember not using a seed)

Any idea is much appreciated!

***EDIT 2:*** OK I figured out how to fulfill all requirement. Thank you all!
***Massimiliano* is the first one who give me correct IDEA how to do it.**

Comment: Generate a random number in [0 50] range. Then add 50. Then square.

Comment: How can random numbers be consecutive, if they are consecutive they are very easily predictable so are not random at all. I would use `lrand48() % 100 + 200` to get a random number between 200 and 300, then square it if so wanted.

Comment: @RonaldinhoState Squares of sequential numbers can't be consecutive! Use a seed to get better results.

Comment: @RonaldinhoState -1 After reading [this](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/139289/should-trivial-questions-that-answer-themselves-be-closed).

Comment: Credit of solution given to Massimiliano. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is definitely more of a math question than a programming question, but the answer is in the question:

```
int n = random(51)+50;
return n*n;
```

Answer (score 1):

Chose a random number in the range of `50 to 100`. Then return its square.

```
int func(){
    int r = random(51); //to choose a random number from 0 to 50.
    r = r + 50; //to scale it to fit form 50 to 100
    return r*r;
}
```

Comment: btw, Ronaldinho is my football idol. :-)